# How does this code for matrices in list work?

Tags: python, matrix

Usually, when we input something into matrices 3x2, and the input numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 it will go like this

A = [ [ 1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]

but I tried something different with my code like this (Not using numpy for matrix)

```
m = int(input('Input m: '))
n = int(input('Input n: '))
a = [[]*n for i in range(m)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        a[j].append(int(input('Masukan angka:')))
```

If I use that code, it goes like
A = [ [1,4],[2,5],[3,6] ] even if I input the number like I mentioned before.

What I cannot understand, is it possible to input from row first then we go for the column? How does this work actually? I can't understand how the code works.

Comment: It's easier to the see the execution by run it via pythontutor.com. Try it and you will find the answer.

Comment: _"is it possible to input from row first then we go for the column?"_ That's what happens in your first approach, isn't it? _"How does this work actually? I can't understand how the code works."_ Step through it with a [debugger.](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) In every `j` iteration, you append the input to the next row until you have rows to append to. Then you move on to the next `i`, which goes to the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Loop one iterates through the range (0,1)

Loop two iterates through the range (0,1,2)

When you append to a[j], you are adding items into only the first index (x) of each [x,y] pair for loop one's first iteration.

In its second iteration you add items into only the second index (y) of each [x,y] pair for loop one's second iteration.

The code below is a minor revision of your original code and works as you have described it should.

```
m = int(input('Input m: '))
n = int(input('Input n: '))
a = [[]*n for i in range(m)]

for i in a:
    for j in range(n):
        i.append(int(input('Masukan angka:')))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I understand now!

Comment: @kgrahadian good to hear. Try experimenting with iterating through your lists in different ways. Using both the `for i in a` format and `for i in range(m)` to help get a better understanding. Programmers new to python may struggle with the `for i in a` format as it represents the item at that index, not its index integer. If the answer has helped resolve your issue, please consider accepting it as an answer.